# Why ClassCastException happens then assign a lambda to a static field?

Tags: java

When using a custom class loader, the direct reference seems wrong.

happens in jdk8u45.

```
import comeon.MyClassLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader();
        Class clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass("comeon.ForTest");
        Field field = clazz.getField("NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER");
        Object o = field.get(null);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

package comeon;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class clazz;
        if (name.startsWith("java")) {
            clazz = getParent().loadClass(name);
        } else {
            clazz = findClass(name);
        }
        if (resolve) {
            resolveClass(clazz);
        }
        return clazz;
    }
    @Override
    public Class findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] b = loadClassFromFile(name);
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }
    private byte[] loadClassFromFile(String fileName)  {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                fileName.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class");
        byte[] buffer;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nextValue = 0;
        try {
            while ( (nextValue = inputStream.read()) != -1 ) {
                byteStream.write(nextValue);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buffer = byteStream.toByteArray();
        return buffer;
    }
}

package comeon;
import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
public class ForTest {
    public static final EntityResolver NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER =
            (publicId, systemId) -> new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
}
```

when initialize NO_OP_ENTITY_RESOLVER, the direct reference's class is loaded by default class loader rather than MyClassLoader.

But when using an anonymous class, it works.

When using 8u221, it works.

Answer (score 0):

*(This answer contains speculation, poorly remembered facts and a lack of experimentation - so don't trust and marked as community wiki.)*

It looks like you have your `ForTest` class loaded twice - once by the system class loader and once by your custom class loader (a child of the system class loader).

IIRC, the Java SE specs say you MUST NOT do this; the Jakarta EE (or whatever it is called nowadays) says you SHOULD do this. *Some of this may have changed for modules.* Also, I believe, certain aspects of lambda implementation have changed.

The Java SE class loader code will always be trying to from the parent class loader. If part of the same class (from the JVM/Java 1.02 point of view, not the `javac`/JLS "fiction"), then you'll definitely get the same class loader. If it's a different class (always the case for nested classes, unfortunately) then your wacky class loader coder code may come into play.